# Re-opening an activity/fragment from a push notification - all previous data is forgotten?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I've implemented a push notification which, when clicked on, takes me to my "home" page (which is a fragment).

However, when the fragment is opened from this push notification, all variables that were assigned on fragment start-up are forgotten.

For example, my `user1` String variable is initially set to `""` as a global variable but changes to a name while the user is in the fragment.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "user1: $user1")
```

However when I open the app from the push notification, `user1` is reset to `""` again, along with all of my other global variables which changed some time after the app was initially opened.

If a user opens an app from a push notification, is the previous state lost?

I presumed it would be the same behaviour as when the user leaves the app and comes back - the data is always remembered - but that is not the case.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with launch modes

Comment: for activity there is "override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent){}" function. and use pending intent in push "PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT".